# Search block on secure pages renders action as http://

Tags: cache, search

My search block:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
...
```

is handled as an unsecure url on secure pages like checkout and is generating mixed content warnings.

The url that I get on checkout is `'http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/'`

I have other sites which include the same block and the search url is served properly. Why would this happen? Can it be because cache? Is there any solution?

Thanks!